# Bytes Downloaded is slightly higher than Total Bytes of a File - Java

Tags: java, download, urlconnection, bufferedinputstream

Well, I'm developing an application which will read the URL entered by user and download the specific file by using `openConnection()` method and etc. I have a function that user can choose the number of remote connections. I did two testings. First with 1 connection and the second test with 4 connections. The problems is with 1 connection the bytes downloaded is same as total bytes of the file but when I try with 4 connection the bytes downloaded are always more than total bytes. So, when I open the downloaded file, it's look corrupted. Here is my code:

Following are code from `DownloadFile.java`

```
SubDownload sd[];
int DownloadID=1, ActiveSubConn=0, BufferSize=1;
long FileSize = 9301;    //bytes
int TotConnections=1;    //by Default '1' for first testing and '4' for second testing
long ld_FStartPos, ld_FEndPos, ld_partsize;
String partname;
String FileLoc = "http://static.webshopapp.com/shops/010317/files/002503512/140x140x2/13-m-kite-refit-service.jpg";

public int StartDownload()
{ 
    sd = new SubDownload[TotConnections];
    ld_partsize= (long)(FileSize/TotConnections);
            System.out.println("FileSize: "+FileSize);

    for (li_conn=0;li_conn < TotConnections ;li_conn++)
    {
        if ( li_conn == (TotConnections - 1))
        {
            ld_FStartPos=li_conn*ld_partsize;
            ld_FEndPos= FileSize;
        }
        else
        {
            ld_FStartPos=li_conn*ld_partsize;
            ld_FEndPos= ld_FStartPos + ld_partsize - 1;
        }

        partname = "DFL" +  String.valueOf(DownloadID) + String.valueOf(li_conn) + ".txt";
        sd[li_conn] = new SubDownload(partname, FileLoc, ld_FStartPos, ld_FEndPos, BufferSize);
        sd[li_conn].start();
        ActiveSubConn = ActiveSubConn + 1;
    }
    return li_conn;          
}
```

Following are code from `SubDownload.java`

```
public  String SubDownloadId, FileLoc;
public  long FileStartPos, FileEndPos, BytesDownloaded=0;
public  byte Buffer[];

public SubDownload(String aSubDownloadId,String aFileLoc,long aFileStartPos,
                long aFileEndPos,int aBufferSize){

    FileLoc=aFileLoc;
    FileStartPos=aFileStartPos;
    FileEndPos=aFileEndPos;
    Buffer = new byte[1024 * aBufferSize];  
    BytesDownloaded=0;
    SubDownloadId=aSubDownloadId;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        URL url = new URL(FileLoc);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream instream;
        uc.setRequestProperty("Range","bytes=" + FileStartPos + "-"+ FileEndPos);

        instream = new BufferedInputStream(uc.getInputStream());

        int li_bytesRead;
        File f = new File(SubDownloadId);
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");

        while(BytesDownloaded < (FileEndPos - FileStartPos))
        {
            if (status ==1)
            {
                if(BytesDownloaded==0) System.out.println("Start: "+FileStartPos+" End: "+FileEndPos);
                li_bytesRead = instream.read(Buffer);
                raf.write(Buffer,0,li_bytesRead);
                BytesDownloaded = BytesDownloaded + li_bytesRead;
                System.out.println("Bytes Read: "+li_bytesRead+" TotalBytesRead: "+BytesDownloaded);
             }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){}


    }
```

Now the Testing part. In the first test I set the `TotConnections=1;` and started the downloaded. Here's the result that printed in the console.

`FileSize: 9301
Start: 0 End: 9301
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 1024
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 2048
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 3072
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 4096
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 5120
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 6144
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 7168
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 8192
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 9216
Bytes Read: 85 TotalBytesRead: 9301`

When I open the downloaded file, it's opened successfully and no errors or corruption occurred. Next in the second testing i set the `TotConnections=4;` and started. The results:

`FileSize: 9301
Start: 4650 End: 6974
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 1024
Bytes Read: 22 TotalBytesRead: 1046
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 2070
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 3094
Start: 6975 End: 9301
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 1024
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 2048
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 3072
Start: 0 End: 2324
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 1024
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 2048
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 3072
Start: 2325 End: 4649
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 1024
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 2048
Bytes Read: 1024 TotalBytesRead: 3072`

If now I open the downloaded file, it's not opening properly. The file is corrupted. In conclusion, the `TotalBytesRead` in first testing is `9301` bytes while for the second testing is `12310` bytes.

If I set the TotConnections to 1, no any problem but other than 1 causing problems. Can someone tell me what's the mistake that I did? Please give me a solution for this.

**Correction: Only sometimes the files downloaded by using 4 or higher than 1 connections are downloaded without corruptions otherwise most of the time the file is being corrupted only.